# How to improve this select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this SQL

```
select *
from t_info
where contract_id <> "" and status <> "unfinished"
order by id asc;
```

but it takes more than 4s. I wonder how to improve this SQL? Thank.

Comment: What does the execution plan of that query tell you? I would assume that a index could help to speed this up

Comment: can you post result of `show create table`, `explain`

Comment: 4 seconds of what? Elapsed time? CPU time? How many rows are there in the table? how many do you end up retrieving at the end of the 4 seconds?

Comment: i'm sorry i can't show you table structure, but the idea of using index do help me a lot,thank you for all comments!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use "<>" in where condition, while you need to use index.

```sql
select * from t_info 
where LENGTH(trim(contract_id)) > 0
and (not status = "unfinished")
order by id asc;
```